# How to copy build artifacts from frontend to backend in IBM BlueMix DevOps

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops, devops-services

I am developing two separated projects: frontend and backend.
I just want to do some steps:

1. Build frontend with `webpack`, build artifacts to build archive directory (/build folder)
2. Copy all of files/folders in build artifacts (/build folder) from frontend to www/public folder in the backend.

Here is my IBM DevOps Toolchains

[image: Toolchains]

And here is my Delivery Pipeline

[image: Pipeline]

Q1: In the DEPLOY FRONTEND stage, how can I copy the build artifacts to the BUILD BACKEND or DEPLOY BACKEND stage?
Please note that I already set the input for DEPLOY FRONTEND stage to be the build artifacts from the BUILD FRONTEND stage.

Q2: How can I get the input build artifacts path in the shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the build artifacts from the "BUILD FRONTEND" in the "BUILD BACKEND" job, you have two options.

1.) As Philippe said, if you aren't using a git input in the "BUILD BACKEND" stage, then simply set the "BUILD BACKEND" input to the stage type and select the "BUILD FRONTEND" stage.

2.) If the "BUILD BACKEND" stage has a git input, then you still need to follow the steps in the first option. After doing this you must configure the build script in the "BUILD BACKEND" to manually pull the git repository you were previously using as input. This usually involves generating oauth2 tokens or personal access tokens depending on the git provider used, for Github see [this link](https://github.com/blog/1270-easier-builds-and-deployments-using-git-over-https-and-oauth). You can store your git credentials or your access tokens as secure properties on your pipeline stage and access them in your script as necessary.

Comment: It's a pity Stage doesn't support multiple input. If it does, we can configure BUILD BACKEND to use both input from BACKEND git repo and the artifacts created in BUILD FRONTEND. Wish this could be enhanced in near future.

Answer (score 1):

Does the BUILD BACKEND need Git repo content ? Or only wants to post process results from BUILD FRONTEND ?
If only post processing, then you can point the BUILD BACKEND stage input to use previous stage build result.

Comment: Yes,  BUILD BACKEND need Git repo content